# Unable to create object

Tags: c#, circular-dependency

There is a .Cs file in one of the projects in my application and i want to create an object of the class(in some other project inside the application) that is inside the .cs file, i tried to add the reference of that particular project but it is giving Circular Dependancy error and i am unable to create the object.

Comment: Do you suspect that you don't actually have a circular dependency?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Break out common code to a third assembly and reference that one in the other two projects.

Answer (score 2):

You get a circular dependency becuase the project in which the object reside already references the project that you want to use the object in. This is probably a design problem as well.

One solution is to create a new project (Common) that both projects can reference.